# asp.net uploading on x64 server 2008

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I publish web site on windows server 2008 x64 with iis 7, I developed the web site using framework 3.5

the site doesn't open , and try to redirect just , while in windows x36 work well

I also noticed the following warning in event log

```
Event code: 3008 
Event message: A configuration error has occurred. 
Event time: 12/15/2011 4:04:54 AM 
Event time (UTC): 12/15/2011 12:04:54 PM 
Event ID: 8ae535fc0b17482b952be80ecd3e65b3 
Event sequence: 1 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-12-129684242945082885 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Machine name: WIN-F1XUWXBQHQ2 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 2732 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpException 
    Exception message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. 

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://localhost/Error.aspx?error=er 
    Request path: /Error.aspx 
    User host address: ::1 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 7 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
 Cannot load assembly system.data 

Custom event details: 


Source :ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0

Event ID: 1310
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable 32-bit applications in the application pool

[image]

Source: http://jepsonsblog.blogspot.com/2010/12/could-not-load-file-or-assembly.html

Comment: Did you restart the app pool after the change? Any more description about the 1309 error? Is the page now displaying?

Comment: Could U give me any details the log say  The current identity (NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE) does not have write access to 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files'.

Comment: Right click on the folder and grant permission for the same user which the application pool runs under. Probably NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE as the message says.